# Jump a Tkinter scrollbar to a certain widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have added some scrollbar functionality to my Tkinter GUI like so

```
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.baseframe)
self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.baseframe, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
self.scrollable = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
self.scrollable.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable, anchor="n")
self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._mousescroll)
```

I have defined `_mousecroll()` as

```
    def _mousescroll(self, event):
        """mouse wheel scroll callback"""
        # Divide the event.delta by some value to effect the scrolling speed
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
```

which is working nicely.

I then add some `tkLabelFrame` widgets to the scroll area (which themselves contain widgets displaying stuff - not relevant for this question). The whole scrolling functionality works really well.

In other part of my GUI, I would like the user to be able to "jump" to a specific point in the scroll area, on a button click. In effect automatically scroll the scroll area to this point. Is this possible? I have full control over the GUI code so I can add labels to the list of tkLabelFrames, store them in some kind of list/dictionary so they can easily be looked up...something like that?

Note: The number of `tkLabelFrames` that are added to the scroll area is dynamic so some kind of absolute "jump to this many pixels" would probably not work. I was hoping there might be some kind of "scroll to a widget with this label/attribute etc.." functionality. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ***"some kind of "scroll to a widget"***: What do you know about the `tkLabelFrame` in question? Index position? Last position? Instance reference? [Edit] your question, remove your `MouseWheel` implementation and show your attempt about: ***scroll to a certain widget*** using [Canvas.yview_moveto-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.yview_moveto-method)

Comment: It's fine, your suggestion was helpful. Perhaps the explanation in my question was also not clear. I want to retain the normal scrolling ability, but have separate functionality to "jump" to a certain point using a button click.

Comment: This may not be useful in your particular case, but if you use a `Text` widget instead of a `Canvas` as the scroll container, you have a `.see()` method that will scroll to make a given position visible - and a reference to an embedded widget can be directly used as a position.  One potential advantage of using `Text` for scrolling is that you can trivially get multiple columns of widgets, if the window is wide enough to hold them - that's just word-wrap in action.

Comment: @jasonharper for my specific usecase, I have already implemented with a canvas. But that could be useful for other users who are coming to this with a blank page and could implement in another way. As mentioned in my answer, my solution works well for widgets of the same height (so using a simple division to index them is OK) but a reference to the widget is better as a generic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my particular scenario, the widgets within the scrollable area where all the same height, so I was able to use a simple fraction to scroll to the correct place.

Adding a button, with a callback to a method like this worked for me:

```
def scrollto(self, idx):
    # Where self.frames is the list of tkLabelFrame objects.
    fraction = float(idx/len(self.frames))

    # self.canvas is my scrollable canvas
    self.canvas.yview_moveto(fraction)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm reviving this because its the first result in google and not everyone's widgets will be the same height (as required by the current accepted answer's solution).

---

Using some .winfo functions, we can do some quick maths to find the widget we want to jump to's exact position within 'self.scrollable'.

**NOTE:** You may need to call .update() on your tkinter instance before calling the jump function, otherwise the winfo values may be incorrect.

---

We will use the following:

- .winfo_height()  -  Get the height of this widget, in pixels. Will return 1 if the window isn’t managed by a geometry manager
- .winfo_rooty()   -  Get the pixel coordinates for the widget’s upper edge, relative to the screen’s upper left corner.
- .yview_moveto(fraction)  -  Move view to location. 0 is the top, 1 is the bottom

---

The following function will jump to the given widget, placing it at the top of the viewable area (self.canvas).

```
 def jump_to_widget_top(self, widget):
      if self.scrollable.winfo_height() > self.canvas.winfo_height():
           pos = widget.winfo_rooty() - self.scrollable.winfo_rooty()
           height = self.scrollable.winfo_height()
           self.canvas.yview_moveto(pos / height)
```

First we check that the container(self.scrollable) is actually larger than the viewing area. No need to jump if everything is already displayed.

We find the absolute position of the desired widget (relative to the screen), then subtract the distance from the top of the container(self.scrollable) to the top of the screen. This gives us the widgets position relative to the position of the container.

With the widget's position found, dividing it by the height of the container(self.scrollable) we get the fractional location of the widget, as required by .yview_moveto().

---

Answer (score 0):

`jump_to_widget_top` by Elija B. works really well as long as the widgets don't change. This is really the fault of the scroll window (so the scroll bars wouldn't work right, either, if you use them). I had to call
`self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))` before computing the `yview_moveto` ratio.

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution to StackOverflow! Could you add a code snippet that shows the `self.canvas.configure(...)` call in-context?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Elijah B's code with my addition

```
def jump_to_widget_top(self, widget):
  # add this if any of the content may have changed size 
  self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))
  if self.scrollable.winfo_height() > self.canvas.winfo_height():
       pos = widget.winfo_rooty() - self.scrollable.winfo_rooty()
       height = self.scrollable.winfo_height()
       self.canvas.yview_moveto(pos / height)
```