# How do I move to tkinter object or particular coordinate

Tags: python, tkinter

I have `self.canvas` which is canvas. Unfortunately the documentation I found is pretty pure in its description and [I found the only one method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) in tkinter (except method for mouse dragging, but I am not including it here because it is not pragmatic) which helps to drag the canvas to the particular object on the canvas (or to some x,y):

```
def move_me_please(self, event):
    self.canvas.xview_moveto(0.1)
```

But it is very inconvenient because 0 is start and 1 is end. If I have canvas 100 000 x 100 000 and I want to move to the x = 36 961, y = 61 468 it will be tricky to do it using this method. I am searching for any other ways to drag the canvas where I actually need (by tags and(or) x, y). I will appreciate any help in this little question.

Comment: It's not clear if you're asking about literaly moving an object (ie: changing its coordinates), or scrolling the canvas until it is in view (leaving the coordinates unchanged, but changing the view of the canvas so that it is visible)

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to leave coords of the object constant and scroll the canvas until object is in a view

Comment: @Alexey ***"very inconvinient because 0 is start and 1 is end"***: You have to compute a fraction, see [Jump to a certain widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824995/7414759)